# Is the function $\sin x$ a transformation of $\cos x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, transformation

In my study of functions I've briefly learnt about transformation of functions wherein we can reflect, stretch , translate or compress a base function (informally) by adding out multiplying a constant to the variable or function itself. Suddenly the graph of trigonometric functions clicked my mind ( ... which I haven't studied in detail ) and I wondered whether function $\sin x$ is a transformation of funcion $\cos x$.

Algebraically $ \ sin^2 x + cos^2 x = 1 $ which shows a relation between the two functions and may be they could be transformed to each other. But here as I don't have a thorough understanding of transformation I don't know whether squaring a function also yields a transformation.

Though I am a bit unsure about it algebraically, geometrically I am firm about my question. This is so because if the cosine function is shifted towards right,  it can certainly be transformed to sine function what I feel intuitively. I may be wrong but these two aspects ( geometric and algebraic) are pestering me to ask  this question .

Please help and thanks.

Comment: Sure. But I think a more useful relation you can use is that $\sin x=\cos(3\pi/2+x)$.

Comment: We can see [here (scroll down most of the way)](http://www.math-prof.com/Trig/Trig_Ch_09.aspx) that $\sin(x+90^\circ)=\cos x$, that is to say $\sin(x+\pi/2)=\cos x$ in radians

Comment: Thanks a lot. One thing I wanted to ask is that you said that sin x = cos ( 270 degrees + x ) is a better relation . Is that so because we are not allowed to transform a function by multiplying it by itself which is not a constant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have commented, yes cosine is a translation of sine (and vice versa) and to be precise $\sin(x + \pi/2) = \cos(x)$ and $\sin(x) = \cos(\pi/2 - x)$. This can be seen if you graph the two function and you will see that they do indeed coincide with one another. If you want a more algebraic proof of this, you can use the sum/difference formulas, which state: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin(\alpha \pm \beta) & = & \sin \alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta \\
\cos(\alpha \pm \beta) & = & \cos \alpha \cos \beta \mp \sin \alpha \sin \beta
\end{eqnarray*}
Using these formulas, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin(x + \pi/2) & = & \sin x \cos \pi/2 + \cos x \sin \pi/2 \\
& = & \sin x \cdot 0 + \cos x \cdot 1 \\
& = & \cos x
\end{eqnarray*}
and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(\pi/2 - x) & = & \cos \pi/2 \cos x + \sin \pi/2 \sin x\\
& = & 0 \cdot \cos x + 1 \cdot \sin x\\
& = & \sin x
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks a lot . One last concern is that while transforming a function can we add or multiply it by a function as we add or multiply constants with variables or function itself to transform it ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking. We can certainly add or multiply two functions together and get a new function thought I am not sure many would necessarily consider that a transformation. Most consider ''transformations'' to only include scaling and shifting (both horizontally and vertically). So if you multiplied a function $f(x)$ by the function $g(x) = c$ for some constant $c$, that would correspond to scaling and adding $g(x)$ would correspond to a vertical shift.

Comment: Is it that when we are adding or multiplying a function to a function the results cannot be generalized as in case of constants and that's why we don't consider it as a transformation. I asked this before also in another question . Anyways thanks again .